# haproxy reverse proxy directing randomly

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy

The reverse proxy of `mydomain.com` is working, but the subdomain `fela.mydomain.com` seems to be randomly picking between `172.17.0.59:8080` and `172.17.0.50:8080`.

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1   local0
    log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  10000
        timeout server  10000

listen stats
    # Uncomment "disabeled" below to disable the stats page :
    # disabled
    bind       :1988
    stats uri /

frontend http-in
        bind *:80

        # Define hosts
        acl host_fela           hdr(host) -i fela.mydomain.com
        acl host_mydomain       hdr(host) -i mydomain.com

        ## figure out which one to use
        use_backend mydomain_cluster       if host_mydomain
        use_backend fela_cluster           if host_fela

backend mydomain_cluster
        balance leastconn
        option httpclose
        option forwardfor
        cookie JSESSIONID prefix
        server node1 172.17.0.50:8080 cookie A check

backend fela_cluster
        balance leastconn
        option httpclose
        option forwardfor
        cookie JSESSIONID prefix
        server node1 172.17.0.59:8080 cookie A check
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to strictly forward all the traffic targeted at fela.mydomain.com to 172.17.0.59:8080 use a different name for that cookie.

```
server node1 172.17.0.59:8080 cookie B check
```